# How to rotate a photo in FireMonkey TWebBrowser

Tags: javascript, image, delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser

I just tried FMX TWebBrowser in Delphi 10.3.3. I could not rotate a photo in img tag. The following page is working in Google Chrome. But it is not working in FireMonkey TWebBrowser of Delphi 10.3.3. What is wrong? Please someone help me!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    img {
      display: block;
      width: 300px;
      height: auto;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="rotate();">Rotate 90 degrees</button>
<br />
<img src="20190228-1.JPG" id="theID" />

<script>
    function rotate() {
      var imgX=document.getElementById("theID");
      imgX.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
      imgX.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess your target platform is Windows. `TWebBrowser` wraps IE based web browser control on Windows which displays pages in IE7 standard mode by default. This mode doesn't support CSS transformations. You have multiple options to workaround that.

### Option 1: Use deprecated `-ms-filter` CSS property

[`-ms-filer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/CSS/-ms-filter) or `filter` is Microsoft CSS extension to apply collection of graphic filters to an object. It also supports rotation:

```js
imgX.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)";
```

### Option 2: Force Egde standard mode via registry

This is also what [`TWebBrowser` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser) encourages you to do on Windows platform. You basically need to enlist your application's EXE name under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` either manually or programmatically as `DWORD` value that defines compatibility mode for your application. `11001` (`$2AF9`) is for IE11 edge mode. See [Browser Emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#browser-emulation) for further values. This setting will affect all pages loaded in any web browser control within your application.

### Option 3: Use `x-ua-compatible` header to specify legacy mode

You should be able to achieve the same effect as in option 2 by injecting `x-ua-compatible` header via `<meta>` tag in your HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
  …
```

See [Specifying legacy document modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/jj676915(v=vs.85)#specifying-legacy-document-modes-1) for more information.

---

All of the above applies to Windows platform. Keep that in mind when picking from the options. Option 1 most likely won't work on other platforms.

While you're at it consider also separating JavaScript from CSS by leveraging CSS classes:

```html
<style>
img {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.rotated {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>

…

<script>
function rotate() {
  var imgX = document.getElementById("theID");
  imgX.classList.toggle("rotated");
}
</script>
```